# jQuery How to .scrollTo() inside .scroll() on if() statement?

Tags: jquery

How do I use `.scrollTo()` with an `if()` statement inside the `.scroll()` handler?

Here's my code so far:

```
scrollToPage = function() {
    $(document).scrollTo($('.page'), 750, { easing: 'easeInOutCubic' });
}

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= ($(this).height()-107)) {
        $('.page').addClass('page-top');
        $('header').css({position: 'fixed'});
    }
    else {
        scrollToPage();      //  This part doesn't work
    }
});
```

So basically, `if` the scrolling reaches a certain point (windowHeight-107), the actual content-page is at the top of the window, and the header will get positioned fixed.

But `else` (when the content-page is not at the top), I want it to scroll automatically to it.

However, it tries to scroll to it again after this first time, everytime I want to scroll further or back. It seems to get stuck.

What's exactly happening here, and how do I get around this?

Anyone?

Comment: So, you want to implement a FIX header which remains fix on top of screen while scrolling.

Comment: @PalashMondal No, that already works... I only want a `scrollTo($('.page'))` when `$(window).scrollTop() <= $(window).height()-107`. But still be able to scroll normally otherwise.

Comment: Are you using any plugin for `scrollTo()` method??

Comment: @PalashMondal Indeed, I use a plugin for that method, which is working fine. Nothing wrong with that. It's just that the `.scroll()` event seems to get stuck or tries to loop, if I use the `.scrollTo()` method inside it.